# In JavaScript, is `return someValue` in a generator function an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, anti-patterns

In the following, the `.next()` can show the last value: `{ value: 3, done: true }`:

```js
function* genFn() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  return 3;
}

const iter = genFn();
console.log(iter.next());
console.log(iter.next());
console.log(iter.next());
```

But not if used as an iterable:

```js
function* genFn() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  return 3;
}

const iter = genFn();
console.log([...iter]);
```

It seems whatever `return value` or no `return` is used, meaning `return undefined`, that value is not used if it is the iterable protocol and therefore also the iterator protocol.

Answer (score 3):

> I think in other words, is `return someValue` in a generator function anti-pattern?

No, but you should only use it when it makes sense. In addition to calling `.next()` manually, `yield*` will produce it.

```js
function* a() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    return 3;
}

function* b() {
    console.log(yield* a());
}

console.log([...b()]);
```

One very practical example of where it made sense was pre-async-functions, where `yield` could be used as an `await` and you’d still want to return a value. The same concept still applies when writing similar patterns that aren’t based on promises/thenables.

Recursion without being limited by the JavaScript call stack, for example:

```js
function* sillyAdd(a, b) {
    return b === 0
        ? a
        : yield sillyAdd(a + 1, b - 1);
}

const restack = f => (...args) => {
    const stack = [f(...args)];
    let ret = undefined;

    while (stack.length !== 0) {
        let {value, done} = stack[stack.length - 1].next(ret);

        if (done) {
            stack.pop();
            ret = value;
        } else {
            stack.push(value);
        }
    }

    return ret;
};

console.log(restack(sillyAdd)(2, 100000));
console.log('(it’s synchronous)');
```

Online parsing by holding state in a paused function:

```js
function* isBalanced() {
    let open = 0;

    for (let c; c = yield;) {
        if (c === '(') {
            open++;
        } else if (c === ')') {
            open--;

            if (open < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return open === 0;
}

class Parser {
    constructor(generator) {
        this.generator = generator();
        const initial = this.generator.next();
        this.done = initial.done;
        this.result = initial.value;
    }

    write(text) {
        if (this.done) {
            return;
        }

        for (const c of text) {
            const {value, done} = this.generator.next(c);

            if (done) {
                this.done = true;
                this.result = value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    finish() {
        if (this.done) {
            return this.result;
        }

        const {value, done} = this.generator.next();

        if (!done) {
            throw new Error('Unexpected end of input');
        }

        return value;
    }
}

const p = new Parser(isBalanced);

// the product of these could be too large to fit in memory
const chunk = '()'.repeat(1000);

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    p.write(chunk);
}

console.log(p.finish());
```

Comment: interesting `yield* a()` will produce it, but what is it used for?

Comment: @nopole: Anything, like a normal return value. `yield` can pause a function. Sometimes you still want to get something from the end of that function. Maybe it seems weird because it doesn’t come up a lot, and that’s true. You probably don’t use the `(yield)` form very often either.